# Largest sublist in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to get the largest sublist from a list using Common Lisp.

```
(defun maxlist (list)
(setq maxlen (loop for x in list maximize (list-length x)))
(loop for x in list (when (equalp maxlen (list-length x)) (return-from maxlist x)))
)
```

The idea is to iterate through the list twice: the first loop gets the size of the largest sublist and the second one retrieves the required list. But for some reason I keep getting an error in the `return-from` line. What am I missing?

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi A syntax error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Main problem with `loop`

There are a few problems here.  First, you can write the loop as the following.  There are `return-from` and `while` forms in Common Lisp, but [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) defines its own little language that also recognizes `while` and `return`, so you can just use those:

```lisp
(loop for x in list
      when (equalp maxlen (list-length x))
      return x)
```

A loop like this can actually be written more concisely with `find` though.  It's just

```lisp
(find maxlen list :key list-length :test 'equalp)
```

Note, however, that `list-length` should always return a number or `nil`, so `equalp` is overkill.  You can just use `eql`, and that's the default for `find`, so you can even write

```lisp
(find maxlen list :key list-length)
```

### `list-length` and `maximize`

`list-length` is a lot like `length`, except that if a list has circular structure, it returns `nil`, whereas it's an error to call `length` with an improper list.  But if you're using `(loop ... maximize ...)`, you can't have `nil` values, so the only case that `list-length` handles that `length` wouldn't is one that will still give you an error.  E.g.,

```lisp
CL-USER> (loop for x in '(4 3 nil) maximize x)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR expected-type: REAL datum: NIL>.
```

(Actually, `length` works with other types of sequences too, so `list-length` would error if you passed a vector, but `length` wouldn't.)  So, if you know that they're all proper lists, you can just

```lisp
(loop for x in list
      maximizing (length x))
```

If they're not all necessarily proper lists (so that you do need `list-length`), then you need to guard like:

```lisp
(loop for x in list
      for len = (list-length x)
      unless (null len) maximize len)
```

### A more efficient argmax

However, right now you're making two passes over the list, and you're computing the length of each sublist twice.  Once is when you compute the maximum length, and the other is when you go to find one with the maximum value. If you do this in one pass, you'll save time.  `argmax` doesn't have an obvious elegant solution, but here are implementations based on `reduce`, `loop`, and `do*`.

```lisp
(defun argmax (fn list &key (predicate '>) (key 'identity))
  (destructuring-bind (first &rest rest) list
    (car (reduce (lambda (maxxv x)
                   (destructuring-bind (maxx . maxv) maxxv
                     (declare (ignore maxx))
                     (let ((v (funcall fn (funcall key x))))
                       (if (funcall predicate v maxv)
                           (cons x v)
                           maxxv))))
                 rest
                 :initial-value (cons first (funcall fn (funcall key first)))))))
```

```lisp
(defun argmax (function list &key (predicate '>) (key 'identity))
  (loop
     for x in list
     for v = (funcall function (funcall key x))
     for maxx = x then maxx
     for maxv = v then maxv
     when (funcall predicate v maxv)
     do (setq maxx x
              maxv v)
     finally (return maxx)))
```

```lisp
(defun argmax (function list &key (predicate '>) (key 'identity))
  (do* ((x (pop list)
           (pop list))
        (v (funcall function (funcall key x))
           (funcall function (funcall key x)))
        (maxx x)
        (maxv v))
       ((endp list) maxx)
    (when (funcall predicate v maxv)
      (setq maxx x
            maxv v))))
```

They produce the same results:

```lisp
CL-USER> (argmax 'length '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6 7 8 9)))
(6 7 8 9)
CL-USER> (argmax 'length '((1 2 3) (6 7 8 9) (4 5)))
(6 7 8 9)
CL-USER> (argmax 'length '((6 7 8 9) (1 2 3) (4 5)))
(6 7 8 9)
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer

Answer (score 3):

### Short variant

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *test* '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6 7 8 9)))
*TEST*
CL-USER> (car (sort *test* '> :key #'length))
(6 7 8 9)
```

### Paul Graham's `most`

Please, consider also Paul Graham's `most` function:

```
(defun most (fn lst)
  (if (null lst)
      (values nil nil)
      (let* ((wins (car lst))
             (max (funcall fn wins)))
        (dolist (obj (cdr lst))
          (let ((score (funcall fn obj)))
            (when (> score max)
              (setq wins obj
                    max score))))
        (values wins max))))
```

This is the result of test (it also returns value that's returned by supplied function for the 'best' element):

```
CL-USER> (most #'length *test*)
(6 7 8 9)
4
```

### `extreme` utility

After a while I came up with idea of `extreme` utility, partly based on Paul Graham's functions. It's efficient and pretty universal:

```
(declaim (inline use-key))
(defun use-key (key arg)
  (if key (funcall key arg) arg))

(defun extreme (fn lst &key key)
  (let* ((win (car lst))
         (rec (use-key key win)))
    (dolist (obj (cdr lst))
      (let ((test (use-key key obj)))
        (when (funcall fn test rec)
          (setq win obj rec test))))
    (values win rec)))
```

It takes comparison predicate `fn`, list of elements and (optionally) `key` parameter. Object with the extreme value of specified quality can be easily found:

```
CL-USER> (extreme #'> '(4 9 2 1 5 6))
9
9
CL-USER> (extreme #'< '(4 9 2 1 5 6))
1
1
CL-USER> (extreme #'> '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6 7 8 9)) :key #'length)
(6 7 8 9)
4
CL-USER> (extreme #'> '((1 2 3) (4 5) (6 7 8 9)) :key #'cadr)
(6 7 8 9)
7
```

*Note that this thing is called `extremum` in alexandria. It can work with sequences too.*

Comment: But why sort the whole list when just one pass through will suffice?  Plus, how many times will this call `length` on each sublist?  `sort` takes a `:key` argument for a reason.  If you do use this approach, it should just be `(sort *test* '> :key 'length)`.  Even there, though, there's no guarantee on how many times the key is called.

Comment: @Joshua, You're right, I just wanted to propose something short.

Comment: Short and clear code definitely has advantages.  For the short case, this isn't too bad, but do be sure to use the facilities that are avilable.  `(sort list '> :key 'length)` is the same approach, but shorter code. :)

Comment: @Joshua, Yes, I've corrected the first variant. That was just first thing that came to mind, you know ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
(defun maxim-list (l)
  (flet ((max-list (a b) (if (> (length a) (length b)) a b)))
    (if (null l)
    nil
    (max-list (car l) (maxim-list (cdr l))))))
```

The `max-list` internal function gets the longest of two list. `maxim-list` is getting the longest of the first list and the `maxim-list` of the rest.

Comment: This code doesn't use tail recursion. Recursive call of `maxim-list` is not the last call in the body of the function. Also consider formatting and moving auxiliary function `max-list` into body of main function (using `flet` for example).