# Find the mode of a list (in common LISP)

Tags: filter, lisp, common-lisp

I need to have a recursive function that uses a custom filter function to return the mode of a list. If there is more than 1 mode, it should return both.

For example: L = (1 3 5 2 3 5) --> ((3 2) (5 2))
Where the first number is the element from the list and the second number is the number of occurrences in the list.

I have the functions that compute the occurrences:

```lisp
;;; FUNCTION NAME: occr2
;;; DESCRIPTION: function counts all occurrences of an element in a list
;;; NOTES: helper function for model

(defun occr2 (k L)
    (cond ((null L) 0)
          ((eql k (first L)) (+ 1 (occr2 k (rest L))))
          (t (occr2 k (rest L)))))

;;; FUNCTION NAME: occr
;;; DESCRIPTION: function returns list of occurrence of each element in a list
;;; NOTES: helper function for model

(defun occr (L)
    (cond ((null L) NIL)
          (t (cons (cons (first L) (cons (occr2 (first L) L) NIL)) (occr (remv (first L) L))))))
```

When I run this on the list '(1 3 5 2 3 5) --> ((1 1) (3 2) (5 2) (2 1))
Now, how can I use a recursive filter function to return only the (3 2) and (5 2)?

Comment: "If there is more than 1 mode, it should return both."  If there's more than one, there could be more than two, as well.

Comment: Since you're already able to do `(1 3 5 2 3 5) --> ((1 1) (3 2) (5 2) (2 1))`, what you need is an argmax function that can maximize for over the second element of the sublists.  (The terminology might help in the research.) Some of the techniques in [Largest sublist in Common Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24166155/1281433) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond homework it might look like this:

```
(defun mode (l &aux (table (make-hash-table)))
  (loop for e in l do (incf (gethash e table 0)))
  (let ((max (loop for v being the hash-value of table maximize v)))
    (loop for key being the hash-keys of table using (hash-value value)
          when (eql value max)
          collect (list key value))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more direct way to compute the mode of a list, but since you've already a "histogram" function that returns a list of each element and its frequency, you can just use an argmax function to find the elemens that maximize the frequency:

```
(defun argmax (function list)
  "ARGMAX returns a list of the elements of LIST that maximize
FUNCTION."
  (if (endp list)
      (error "Cannot maximize over an empty list.")
      (destructuring-bind (best &rest list) list
        (do* ((bests (list best))
              (max (funcall function best)))
             ((endp list) bests)
          (let* ((x (pop list))
                 (val (funcall function x)))
            (cond
              ((> val max)
               (setf bests (list x)
                     max val))
              ((= val max)
               (push x bests))))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (argmax 'second '((1 1) (3 2) (5 2) (2 1)))
((5 2) (3 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to finally come up with. For my class, we are not allowed to use built-in functions. I basically find the highest occurrence of any value, and compare each elements occurrence to that value, filtering out any element that is less than the mode value. This way if 2+ elements have the same occurrence, the filter still keeps them.

```lisp
;;; FUNCTION NAME: occr2
;;; DESCRIPTION: function counts all occurrences of an element in a list
;;; NOTES: helper function for model

(defun occr2 (k L)
    (cond ((null L) 0)
          ((eql k (first L)) (+ 1 (occr2 k (rest L))))
          (t (occr2 k (rest L)))))

;;; FUNCTION NAME: occr
;;; DESCRIPTION: function returns list of occurrence of each element in a list
;;; NOTES: helper function for model

(defun occr (L)
    (cond ((null L) NIL)
          (t (cons (cons (first L) (cons (occr2 (first L) L) NIL)) (occr (remv (first L) L))))))

;;; FUNCTION NAME: filter
;;; DESCRIPTION: function filters elements out of a list based on a boolean function parameter
;;; NOTES: helper function for model

(defun filter (F L)
    (cond ((null L) NIL)
          ((funcall F (first L)) (cons (first L) (filter F (rest L))))
          (t (filter F (rest L)))))

;;; FUNCTION NAME: findmax
;;; DESCRIPTION: function finds the max occurrence of elements in a list
;;; NOTES: helper function for model

(defun findmax (L)
    (cond ((null (rest L)) (second (first L)))
          ((> (second (first L)) (second (second L)))
           (findmax (cons (first L) (rest (rest L)))))
          (t (findmax (cons (second L) (rest (rest L)))))))

;;; FUNCTION NAME: model
;;; DESCRIPTION: function uses filter to return the mode(s) of a list of elements
;;; NOTES: uses occr, occr2, filter, and findmax helper functions

(defun model (L)
  (filter (lambda (x)
            (>= (second x) (findmax (occr L))))
          (occr L)))
```

(model '(1 3 5 2 3 5)) --> ((3 2) (5 2))

(model '(1 3 5 2 4 5)) --> ((5 2))

There may be a simpler way to do this, but this does work.

Comment: In `model`: not a good idea to compute `findmax` more than one time.

Comment: "we are not allowed to use built-in functions"  You should have mentioned that in the question.  And you *are* still using lots of built in functions: null, rest, second, first, >, cons,  and eql, to name a few.  If you have a specific requirement about what you can and can't use, you need to mention it in the question.  At any rate, if this is the solution that worked for you, be sure to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437) after any time limit is finished.